# Raise an error if a subquery returns no result (MS SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server

In DB2 it is possible to raise an error if a subquery returns no results with the help of coalesce and the raise_error scalar function.

**But how can this be done in sql server?**

I checked scalar functions so far, but there is no raise error function which can be used in a single query.

The use case is about finding a matching value in another table during an export of millions of records. So, for every record in the query a matching value is looked up. The idea is to raise an error if there is no matching value for a record so it is detected early and not after the whole query is run.

example for db2 (note: the subquery needs to be replaced by something meaningful...):

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 LIMIT 0), 
        RAISE_ERROR('70NUL', 'Value is missing')) 
FROM 
    SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

Comment: solution for oracle here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71840014/raise-an-error-if-a-subquery-returns-no-result/

Comment: This can't be done cleanly in a single statement in T-SQL, at least not one that's supposed to also return results. You can hack it by forcing an error if an expression is `NULL` (for example, by forcing evaluating of a division by zero) but that will just produce obscure error messages. For a clean solution you'll need to assign to a variable, then check and `THROW` (or, assuming you only need to check for any result, a simple `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...) THROW ...` without an assignment will do).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [RAISEERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
RAISERROR ('Oups', 1, 1)
```

EDIT

As Lamu pointed out, it is also possible to use `THROW`, as in

```
    PRINT 'In catch block.';  
    THROW;
```

Comment: thought so... but I can't SELECT RAISERROR('OUPS', 1, 1);

Comment: I would suggest `THROW` over `RAISERROR`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I'll continue with:

```sql
   SELECT COALESCE ((select 1), 'Query aborted. This is the error message' / 0);
   -- returns 1

   SELECT COALESCE ((select null), 'Query aborted. This is the error message' / 0);
   -- query aborts showing message

   SELECT COALESCE ((select null WHERE 1=2), 'Query aborted. This is the error message' / 0);
   -- query aborts showing message
```